# Volley ImageLoader really slow on older devices

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-volley

Has anyone been able to test Volley on older devices?

I have a ZTE Blade which has a single core 800mhz cpu.

I've found that Volley will just sit there waiting for 4-5 seconds or even longer before loading the images, even when they are already on disk.

The same code is absolutely blisteringly fast on my Galaxy S2 and Xoom.

I've used Universal-Image-Loader, and it has no problems on the older device, everything snappy.

Not really sure how to debug this.

I've even gone into the internals a bit even removing the sync object from the bitmap decode, but to absolutely no avail.

I have a new app to release and have had to release without pre-ICS support because of the performance is just so bad.

Comment: Traceview might be able to show you where the bottleneck is. You might also consider whether Volley was a wise choice, since it is undocumented and unsupported.

Comment: Yeah working on Universal-image-loader reimplementation after another stab at the problem tomorrow. Will have to dig into traceview perhaps, haven't used that before.

Comment: To add fuel to this fire. The latest play store app which apparently uses Volley, is really slow to load images on this older device. Exact same problem, I could be staring at an entire page of thumbnails / icons on the play store and it will take 30s at a time before loading any of the images. I mean I can navigate around, install apps and continue browsing before even a single image loads.

Comment: It is conceivable that ZTE made some modifications to an HTTP stack that Volley does not take into consideration. This sort of thing has happened before (e.g., HTC changing a 2K allocation in `HttpClient` to a 4MB allocation and causing a bunch of `OutOfMemoryErrors`). For your own code, you could try switching Volley to use `OKHttp` as its HTTP implementation, which would be independent of anything ZTE might have modified (at least, north of the kernel). See https://plus.google.com/108284392618554783657/posts/eJJxhkTQ4yU

Comment: Yeah, I've been using OkHttp as the stack on the production version. But I just figured out the problem, so I'll post an answer.

Comment: If you don't mind, post another comment here when you post the answer, as I'd be interested in taking a peek at it.

Comment: Beep, watched the talk again which explained some of the internals. Noticed the batched response in the image loader and disabling that actually made my problems go away. So I can't sit there looking at images unloaded for long periods of time. I think there is still some work to do, after enabling debugging, a LOT of time is spent in cache queue, so I'm going to be investigating that further. But the core of the problem I consider fixed... but it's unclear why because the batching is meant to result in near indefinite delays...

Comment: Another thing to note here is if you've loaded a lot of images (which will get stored in the disk cache), it can take a while for Volley to reinitialize the cache the first time it starts up.  It cycles through all of the files stored on disk to rebuild the `LinkedHashMap` used by `DiskBasedCache`.  I was able to improve on this significantly by saving/loading a serialized copy of the hash map.

Comment: Care to share your optimisation potatoe? I'll be sure to give it a +1.

I recently got hold of an HTC desire, and it's slow on that still, so it isn't ZTE specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour of ImageLoader in Volley seems to be tuned for "pages" of thumbnails and not so much a much longer or contiguous stream. To that end, responses from the ImageLoader are actually delayed / batched up before being delivered. So images that are ready are not being delivered as soon as they possible can be to achieve a sort of page load aesthetic, aluded to briefly in the Google I/O talk.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo

You can remove this behaviour with the following

```
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mQueue, imageCache);
mImageLoader.setBatchedResponseDelay(0);
```

I'm not sure why this causes any problems at the end of the day though, because it's only meant to delay by 100ms, and I don't see it extending that delay based on new content arriving, but will continue to investigate and report back on anything else I find. But this does fix the responsiveness on older devices and newer devices are of course still buttery.

Comment: would have given you a double up vote if i could. oh i know!